# Как обновить owl-carousel с версии 1.3.3 до 2

Tags: opencart, owl-carousel

Не могу правильно обновить owl-carousel в opencart2.

Из коробки opencart 2 использует старую версию 1.3.3. Замена файлов приводит к тому что есть ошибки в инспекторе и некоторые функции не понимает и слетают стили. Как безопасно обновиться на opencart?

Comment: `есть ошибки в инспекторе` – какие ошибки? `некоторые функции не понимает` – какие функции? `и слетают стили` — ...

Comment: во 2м немного поменялись параметры и теперь подключать надо несколько библиотек. Вам надо на офф.сайт карусели. https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/started-welcome.html там очень просто и понятно показано.